# Display result in order of tag matching frequency

Tags: php, sql

I have written a code to search for ads using tags. The code delimits(space) the search string entered by the user and matches each word with the tag in database separated by commas using LIKE clause. I am getting correct result. But what i want is that the row which matches more tags with the search strings word should appear at the top.

For example:- tag in 1st rows(in db) is  "samung,mobile,phone" and in the 2nd row its "samsung,phone" and the search string is "samsung mobile phone" then the 1st row should appear first as it has more matches then 2nd row. How can i do it using ORDER BY.

My code is:-

```
<?php  require_once("db_connect.php");  ?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="searchtext" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$searchquery = $_POST["searchtext"];
$searcharray = array();

$searcharray = explode(" ",$searchquery);
if(!isset($searcharray[1]))
$searcharray[1] = "XXXXXXXX";
if(!isset($searcharray[2]))
$searcharray[2] = "XXXXXXXX";
if(!isset($searcharray[2]))
$searcharray[2] = "XXXXXXXX";
if(!isset($searcharray[3]))
$searcharray[3] = "XXXXXXXX";


$query = "select * from search where tag LIKE '%$searcharray[0],%' OR tag LIKE '%$searcharray[1],%' OR tag LIKE '%$searcharray[2],%' OR tag LIKE '%$searcharray[3],%' ";

$result=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row["name"]. '<br>' ;


}
```

Comment: What about MySQL [**FULLTEXT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html) search?

Comment: What you should do is move the tags into a properly normalized table, so you can use `WHERE tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', ...)`. Then you can index the tag column and it will be much more efficient, and use `COUNT(*)` to count the number of matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison operators return 0 or 1 depending on whether they matches, so you can add them to count the number of matches:

```
$searcharray = explode(" ",$searchquery);
$matchexpr = implode(' + ', array_map(function($x) { return "(find_in_set('$x', tag) > 0)";}, $searcharray));

$query = "select *, 
                 ($matchexpr) as matches
         from search
         having matches > 0
         order by matches desc";
```

Comment: I am getting error:-  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource. I don't now why it's not returning  any result as such pattern exist in my table.

Comment: var_dump($query); is displaying:-      string 'select *, 
                 (tag LIKE '%mobile,%' + tag LIKE '%XXXXXXXX,%' + tag LIKE '%XXXXXXXX,%' + tag LIKE '%XXXXXXXX,%') as matches         from search having matches > 0 order by matches desc' (length=220)

Comment: That's what I expect, is there a problem with it?

Comment: I know the output is expected but why mysql_fetch_array() is not returning anything.

Comment: Check for errors from `mysql_query()`. I've updated my answer to allow any number of search terms, and not do all that XXX stuff.

Comment: What error are you getting? One thing to watch out for is that you're putting `,` in the `LIKE` pattern. If the tag is the last one in the list, it doesn't end with `,`.

Comment: I am adding comma even after the last tag like "sony,mobile,"

Comment: I've rewritten the query to use `find_in_set`, which is a better way to search for matches in a comma-separated list.

Comment: It is giving unexpected result. What i want is if even a single word matches with the tag that result shoould be returned.

Comment: That's what this does. It counts the number of matched tags, and returns all the rows where count > 0.

Comment: I have four tags "samsung,psp," "sony,mobile," "sony,psp,"  "mobile,nokia,samsung,"   When i am entering samsung mobile then only 2 rows are returned but  words are matching with 3 rows out of 4.  "sony,mobile," row is not returning.

Comment: Are there any spaces around the commas? That won't match.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer at the bottom.

Comment: Figured it out, it's an operator precedence problem. I added parentheses, I think that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

No there are no spaces around the commas.

I have changed the line :-

```
$matchexpr = implode(' + ', array_map(function($x) { return "find_in_set('$x', tag) > 0";}, $searcharray));
```

to

```
$matchexpr = implode(' OR ', array_map(function($x) { return "find_in_set('$x', tag) > 0";}, $searcharray));
```

Its getting the rows correctly but the order is not correct. Its returning the rows as in the original order i think its because OR does not concatenate the returned value.

Using ur code :_

"samsung mobile" word is returning 2 result (viv and samsung psp).
"mobile samsung" is returning only 1 result (sony mobile).

Comment: This is basically like your original code, since OR just return 0 or 1 depending on whether any of the conditions are true. If you want them sorted, you have to use + to count the number of matches.